# JQuery autocomplete text search with results from remote source

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, django

I'm trying to implement an input field with an autocomplete feature. I'd be using Google Books API to autocomplete names of books based on the keyword that the user enters in the input text field. I'd be using Django as my framework to implement this feature.

This is what I have been able to do so far:

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    $("#id_book_name").on("change paste keyup", function()
    {
        var app_url = document.location.origin;
        var book_name = $('#id_book_name').val();
        var url = app_url+'/book-search/';
        if(book_name.length > 4)
        {
            var data = {
                'book_name': book_name,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
            };
            console.log(data);
            $.post(url, data).done(function(result)
            {
                for(var book_title of result)
                {
                    console.log(book_title);
                }
                console.log(result);
            }).fail(function(error)
            {
                console.log(error)
            });
            return false;
        } 

    }); 
});
```

Here, `#id_book_name` is the id of my input text field. As soon as the length of the keyword entered by the user exceeds 4, I'm sending a POST request to `/book-search` which is mapped to the following Python function where I hit Google Books API's endpoint and return the book titles in a specific JSON format:

```
def book_search(request):
    book_results = {'titles':[]}
    key = 'XXXXXXX'
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + request.POST['book_name'] + '&maxResults=5&key=' + key
    result = requests.get(url)
    json_result = json.loads(result.text)
    if 'items' in json_result:
        for e in json_result['items']:
            if 'industryIdentifiers' in e['volumeInfo']:
                isbn = ''
                for identifier in e['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers']:
                    isbn = identifier['identifier'] if (identifier['type'] == 'ISBN_10') else isbn
                if 'subtitle' in e['volumeInfo']:
                    book_results['titles'].append(e['volumeInfo']['title'] + ' - ' 
                        + e['volumeInfo']['subtitle'] + ' (' + isbn + ')')
                else:
                    book_results['titles'].append(e['volumeInfo']['title'] + ' (' + isbn + ')')
    result = json.dumps(book_results)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

Sample return format of the above function for keyword 'python':

```
{"titles": ["Python - A Study of Delphic Myth and Its Origins (0520040910)", "Python Machine Learning (1783555149)", "Learn Python the Hard Way - A Very Simple Introduction to the Terrifyingly Beautiful World of Computers and Code (0133124347)", "Natural Language Processing with Python - Analyzing Text with the Natural Language Toolkit (0596555717)", "Python (0201748843)"]}
```

Now, what I'm not able to figure out is how to loop through the above JSON format to display the results below my input text field. I know I can use the `append()` JQuery function to add my book titles inside the `<li>` tags. However, I'm stuck on how to loop through my response result to individually get each book title using a for loop:

```
for(var book_title of result)
{
   console.log(book_title);
}
```

I'm new to JQuery, and would really appreciate some guidance on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is quite simple. One way to achieve this is ..please follow the comments

```js
$(function() {

  var myDiv = $("#mydiv"); //Assuming there is a div wrapped 
  var myUl = $('<ul/>'); //blank unordered list object

  //Your result from the query
  var result = JSON.parse('{"titles": ["Python - A Study of Delphic Myth and Its Origins (0520040910)", "Python Machine Learning (1783555149)", "Learn Python the Hard Way - A Very Simple Introduction to the Terrifyingly Beautiful World of Computers and Code (0133124347)", "Natural Language Processing with Python - Analyzing Text with the Natural Language Toolkit (0596555717)", "Python (0201748843)"]}');

  //Iterate through each object
  result.titles.forEach(function(item) {
    var li = $('<li/>'); //create an li item object
    li.append(item); // append the item/txt to the list item
    myUl.append(li); //append the list item to the list
  });
  myDiv.append(myUl) //Append list to the div

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mydiv'>
  <input id='id_book_name' />
</div>
```

Let us know

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no reason to return a one-key dictionary. Just return the array. So, your result would look more like:

```js
["Python - A Study of Delphic Myth and Its Origins (0520040910)", "Python Machine Learning (1783555149)", "Learn Python the Hard Way - A Very Simple Introduction to the Terrifyingly Beautiful World of Computers and Code (0133124347)", "Natural Language Processing with Python - Analyzing Text with the Natural Language Toolkit (0596555717)", "Python (0201748843)"]
```

Then, you pass a fourth parameter to `$.post`, the datatype of JSON, so it always automatically parses it into a JavaScript array.

```js
$.post(url, data, onSuccess, 'json').fail(onFail);
```

Then you just have a simple array to append to search results.

Make an array of, say, 5 suggestions, and only fill the top 5 (As more would probably be uneccessary). Then use CSS to hide empty ones (Like `#auto-complete :empty { display: none; }`). Your `onSuccess` function could look like (Assuming you have a `ol` or `ul` element with the id `auto-complete` that has 5 `li` elements):

```js
var autoCompleteBoxes = $('#auto-complete li');

$.post(url, data, function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        autoCompleteBoxes[i].text(data[i] || '');
    }
}, 'json').fail(function() {
    // Reset auto complete boxes if there was a failure.
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        autoCompleteBoxes[i].text('');
    }
    $('#auto-complete').hide();
}
```